# Split text file into lines with fixed number of words

Tags: text-processing, sed, awk, split

Related, but no satisfactory answers: [How can I split a large text file into chunks of 500 words or so?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/66513/how-can-i-split-a-large-text-file-into-chunks-of-500-words-or-so)

I'm trying to take a text file (http://mattmahoney.net/dc/text8.zip) with > 10^7 words all in one line, and split it into lines with N words each. My current approach works, but is fairly slow and ugly (using shell script):

```
i=0
for word in $(sed -e 's/\s\+/\n/g' input.txt)
do
    echo -n "${word} " > output.txt
    let "i=i+1"

    if [ "$i" -eq "1000" ]
    then
        echo > output.txt
        let "i=0"
    fi
done
```

Any tips on how I can make this faster or more compact?

Comment: if you want it faster, you need to use something else then bash script. I would recommend some C. It can fit to few lines.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming your definition of word is a sequence of non-blank characters separated by blanks, here's an `awk` solution for your single-line file

```
awk '{for (i=1; i<=NF; ++i)printf "%s%s", $i, i % 500? " ": "\n"}i % 500{print ""}' file
```

Answer (score 15):

Use `xargs` (17 seconds):

```
xargs -n1000 <file >output
```

It uses the `-n` flag of `xargs` which defines the max number of arguments. Just change `1000` to `500` or whatever limit you want.

I made a test file with 10^7 words:

```
$ wc -w file
10000000 file
```

Here are the time stats:

```
$ time xargs -n1000 <file >output
real    0m16.677s
user    0m1.084s
sys     0m0.744s
```

Comment: This is slightly slower than the answer I accepted (21s vs 12s on my file)

Comment: Excellent idea +1, however beware `xargs`'s [quote-stripping behaviour](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/38148/why-does-xargs-strip-quotes-from-input)

Comment: The lower the `n` the slower this will get, just so you know. With `-n10` I cancelled it after about 8 minutes of waiting...

Comment: That worked very well for me. I especially like the simplicity of the approach ...

Answer (score 7):

Perl seems quite astonishingly good at this:

Create a file with 10,000,000 space separated words

```
for ((i=1; i<=10000000; i++)); do printf "%s " $RANDOM ; done > one.line
```

Now, perl to add a newline after each 1,000 words

```
time perl -pe '
    s{ 
        (?:\S+\s+){999} \S+   # 1000 words
        \K                    # then reset start of match
        \s+                   # and the next bit of whitespace
    }
    {\n}gx                    # replace whitespace with newline
' one.line > many.line
```

Timing

```
real    0m1.074s
user    0m0.996s
sys     0m0.076s
```

verify results

```
$ wc one.line many.line
        0  10000000  56608931 one.line
    10000  10000000  56608931 many.line
    10000  20000000 113217862 total
```

The accepted awk solution took just over 5 sec on my input file.

Answer (score 5):

Not really suitable when `N`umber of words is a big number but if it's a small number (and ideally, no leading/trailing spaces in your one-line file) this should be quite fast (e.g. 5 words per line):

```
tr -s '[[:blank:]]' '\n' <input.txt | paste -d' ' - - - - - >output.txt
```

Comment: This is perfectly fine with large numbers as well, and blindingly fast. Just generate the `paste` string on the fly. For example: `tr -s '[[:blank:]]' '\n' < text8 | paste -d' ' $(perl -le 'print "- " x 1000')`

Comment: @terdon - true, though for large numbers one has to build up the command arguments e.g. as you did or via `set` etc... and even then, there's a sytem specific max number of arguments (I'm not familiar with all flavors of `paste` but I think with some implementations there are limits as to no. of args/input files and/or output line length...)

Answer (score 4):

The same sed command can be simplified by specifying how many word-space patterns you want to match. I didn't have any big string files to test it out on, but without the loops in your original script this should run as fast as your processor can stream the data. Added benefit, it'll work equally well on multi-line files.

```
n=500; sed -r "s/((\w+\s){$n})/\1\n/g" <input.txt >output.txt
```

Answer (score 3):

The venerable `fmt(1)` command, while not strictly operating on "a particular number of words" can fairly quickly wrap long lines to a particular goal (or maximum) width:

```
perl -e 'for (1..100) { print "a"x int 3+rand(7), " " }' | fmt
```

Or with modern perl, for a specific number of words, say, 10, and
assuming a single space as the word boundary:

```
... | perl -ple 's/(.*? ){10}\K/\n/g'
```

Answer (score 2):

The coreutils `pr` command is another candidate: the only wrinkle seems to be that it is necessary to force the page width to be large enough to accommodate the output width.

Using a file created using @Glenn_Jackman's 10,000,000 word generator,

```
$ time tr '[[:blank:]]' '\n' < one.line | pr -s' ' -W 1000000 -JaT -1000 > many.line

real    0m2.113s
user    0m2.086s
sys 0m0.411s
```

where the counts are confirmed as follows

```
$ wc one.line multi.line 
        0  10000000  56608795 one.line
    10000  10000000  56608795 many.line
    10000  20000000 113217590 total
```

[Glenn's perl solution is still a little faster, ~1.8s on this machine].

Answer (score 1):

in Go I would try it like this

```
//wordsplit.go

//$ go run wordsplit.go bigtext.txt

package main


import (
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
    "log"
    "os"
    "strings"
)


func main() {
    myfile, err := os.Open(os.Args[0])
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    defer myfile.Close()
    data, err := ioutil.ReadAll()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    words := strings.Split(data, " ")
    newfile, err := os.Create("output.txt")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    defer newfile.Close()
    for i := 0; i < len(words)-10; i+10 {
        newfile.WriteString(words[i:i+10])
    }
    newfile.WriteString(words[-(len(words)%10):])
    fmt.Printf("Formatted %s into 10 word lines in output.txt", os.Args[0])
}
```